# Why must a call to a function be enclosed in function()

Tags: javascript

Coming from a standard programming language, I find this snippet of javascript hard to understand:

(from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

```
var myVar=setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

Why is the call to myTimer() further enclosed in function(){}, it *is* a function. And isn't setInterval() expecting a function? So why not just refer to the function directly? as in:

```
var myVar=setInterval(myTimer(), 1000);
```

What I also don't understand is that the above actually runs once. Why is that? (If it is incorrect then it should not work at all)

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate, but can't find one easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the reference just use the function name without `()`.

```
var myVar=setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
```

When `()` is used the function is invoked and the returned value is passed to the `setInterval`

Comment: Thanks, both answers add to the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> So why not just refer to the function directly? as in:

```
var myVar=setInterval(myTimer(), 1000);
```

Because then the result of `myTimer` call is passed. Functions aren't different to any other value when you pass them to other functions.